# Python Tkinter Graph

Tags: python, graph, tkinter

I'd like to make a program which takes an integer from user and makes as many entries in a Tkinkter window. Than from those entries take data and make a graph base on them. But when i turn on my program evereything is fine only a graph is wrong. It shows me an empty graph without any data on it, with no title and no "labels names". Here is my code. Please help. I'm using Python 2.7.5, PyDev for Eclipse

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-



import matplotlib.pyplot as mp
import Tkinter as T, sys
def end():
    sys.exit()
def check():
    z = e.get()
    try:
        z = int(z)
        e.config(bg = 'green')
        e.after(1000, lambda: e.config(bg = 'white'))

        x = []
        y = []
        global x1, y1
        x1 = []
        y1 = []
        l2 = T.Label(main, text = 'X',bg = 'yellow')
        l2.pack()
        for i in range(0,z):
            x.append(T.Entry(main, justify = 'center'))
            x[i].pack()
            x1.append(x[i].get())
        l3 = T.Label(main, text = 'Y', bg = '#3366ff')
        l3.pack()
        for i in range(0,z):
            y.append(T.Entry(main, justify = 'center'))
            y[i].pack() 
            y1.append(y[i].get())
    except:
        e.config(bg = 'red')
        e.after(1000, lambda: e.config(bg = 'white'))
    return x1,y1


def graph():
    mp.ion()
    mp.plot(x1,y1)  
    mp.title('Wykres')
    mp.xlabel('x')
    mp.ylabel('y')
    mp.draw()






#====================================================================#

y1 = []
x1 = []
z = 0
main = T.Tk()
main.title('GRAPH')
main.geometry('600x600')
main.config(bg = "#3366ff")

e = T.Entry(main,justify = 'center')
l = T.Label(main,text = 'Podaj liczbę parametrów N =',bg = '#3366ff')
b1 = T.Button(main, text = 'OK', command = check)

b2 = T.Button(main, text = 'Rysuj', command = graph)
b = T.Button(main,text = 'Zakończ', command = end)





l.pack()
e.pack()
b1.pack()

b2.pack()
b.pack()
main.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GB: x1, x2 have only empty strings. You have to get values from `Entry` in `graph()` function when `Entry` have some value - and remember to convert it from string to integer.

PL: x1, x2 zawierają tylko puste stringi. Musisz pobrać wartości z `Entry` w funkcji `graph()` kiedy `Entry` już zawierają jakieś wartości - i pamiętaj przekonwertować je z napisów na liczby

working code / działający kod

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import matplotlib.pyplot as mp
import Tkinter as T, sys

class Application():

    def __init__(self, root):

        self.root = root

        self.x1 = []
        self.y2 = []

        self.z = 0

        self.root.title('GRAPH')
        self.root.geometry('600x600')
        self.root.config(bg="#3366ff")

        self.e = T.Entry(self.root, justify='center')

        self.l = T.Label(self.root, text='Podaj liczbę parametrów N =', bg='#3366ff')

        self.b1 = T.Button(self.root, text='OK', command=self.check)

        self.b2 = T.Button(self.root, text='Rysuj', command=self.graph)
        self.b = T.Button(self.root, text='Zakończ', command=self.end)

        self.l.pack()
        self.e.pack()
        self.b1.pack()

        self.b2.pack()
        self.b.pack()

    #------------------------------------------------------------

    def run(self):
        self.root.mainloop()

    #------------------------------------------------------------

    def end(self):
        sys.exit()

    #------------------------------------------------------------

    def check(self):
        try:
            self.entry_x = []
            self.entry_y = []

            self.z = int(self.e.get())

            self.e.config(bg='green')
            self.e.after(1000, lambda: self.e.config(bg='white'))

            self.l2 = T.Label(self.root, text='X', bg='yellow')
            self.l2.pack()

            for i in range(self.z):
                self.entry_x.append(T.Entry(self.root, justify='center'))
                self.entry_x[-1].pack()

            self.l3 = T.Label(self.root, text='Y', bg='#3366ff')
            self.l3.pack()

            for i in range(self.z):
                self.entry_y.append(T.Entry(self.root, justify='center'))
                self.entry_y[-1].pack() 
        except:
            self.e.config(bg='red')
            self.e.after(1000, lambda: self.e.config(bg='white'))

    #------------------------------------------------------------

    def graph(self):

        self.x1 = []
        self.y1 = []

        for i in range(len(self.entry_x)):
            self.x1.append(float(self.entry_x[i].get()))

        for i in range(len(self.entry_y)):
            self.y1.append(float(self.entry_y[i].get()))

        mp.ion()
        mp.plot(self.x1, self.y1)  
        mp.title('Wykres')
        mp.xlabel('x')
        mp.ylabel('y')
        mp.draw()

#====================================================================#

Application(T.Tk()).run()
```